# Cannot access NODE0000 when starting DB2 11.5 from Docker

Tags: docker, db2

I'm trying to start the DB2 docker image on my Mac (M1) for testing, but I'm getting a permission issue.

```
03/31/2023 11:55:21     0   0   SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
(*) Cataloging existing databases
ls: cannot access /database/data/db2inst1/NODE0000: No such file or directory
```

This is the command to reproduce it:

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64/v8 -e LICENSE=accept --rm -it ibmcom/db2:11.5.0.0a bash
```

How do I start the image successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run the command in privileged mode. Also, running on M1 (ARM) requires running the container in emulation mode. Here is a command that will completely setup your test container:

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64/v8 --privileged=true --user 0 \
-e "LICENSE=accept" \
-e "DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1" \
-e "DB2INST1_PASSWORD=admin" \
-e "DBNAME=mydb2" \
-e "TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true" \
-e "ENABLE_ORACLE_COMPATIBILITY=false" \
-e "UPDATEAVAIL=NO" \
-e "IS_OSXFS=false" \
-e "REPODB=false" \
-e "PERSISTENT_HOME=true" ibmcom/db2:11.5.0.0a bash
```

If not running on ARM, just omit the platform flag, like this:

```
docker run --privileged=true --user 0 \
-e "LICENSE=accept" \
-e "DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1" \
-e "DB2INST1_PASSWORD=admin" \
-e "DBNAME=mydb2" \
-e "TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=true" \
-e "ENABLE_ORACLE_COMPATIBILITY=false" \
-e "UPDATEAVAIL=NO" \
-e "IS_OSXFS=false" \
-e "REPODB=false" \
-e "PERSISTENT_HOME=true" ibmcom/db2:11.5.0.0a bash
```